# Generate available time slot list from Google Calendar

Tags: windows-7, chrome, calendar

I am looking for a program (Windows 7), Google Chrome extension, or script that can look at my Google Calendar and generate a list of time slots when I am available for the next X days, e.g. :

- Monday, April 13 from 10 AM to 1 PM
- Monday, April 13 any time after 3 PM
- Tuesday, April 14 any time after 1 PM
- Wednesday, April 15 from 10 AM to 1 PM
- Wednesday, April 15 any time after 3 PM
- Friday, April 17 any time after 11:30 AM
- Monday, April 20 from 10 AM to 1 PM
- Monday, April 20 any time after 3 PM
- Tuesday, April 21 any time after 1 PM
- Wednesday, April 22 from 10 AM to 1 PM
- Wednesday, April 22 any time after 3 PM
- Friday, April 24 any time after 11:30 AM
- etc.

Answer (score 3):

With [python](http://python.org) plus the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/calendar/v3) you can use the `calendar.freebusy.query` method. This can also be used from Google App Engine and you can find more information [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/).

This returns returns:
  An object of the form:

```
{
"timeMax": "A String", # The end of the interval.
"kind": "calendar#freeBusy", # Type of the resource ("calendar#freeBusy").
"calendars": { # List of free/busy information for calendars.
  "a_key": { # Free/busy expansions for a single calendar.
    "busy": [ # List of time ranges during which this calendar should be regarded as busy.
      {
        "start": "A String", # The (inclusive) start of the time period.
        "end": "A String", # The (exclusive) end of the time period.
      },
    ],
    "errors": [ # Optional error(s) (if computation for the calendar failed).
      {
        "domain": "A String", # Domain, or broad category, of the error.
        "reason": "A String", # Specific reason for the error. Some of the possible values are:
            # - "groupTooBig" - The group of users requested is too large for a single query.
            # - "tooManyCalendarsRequested" - The number of calendars requested is too large for a single query.
            # - "notFound" - The requested resource was not found.
            # - "internalError" - The API service has encountered an internal error.  Additional error types may be added in the future, so clients should gracefully handle additional error statuses not included in this list.
      },
    ],
  },
},
"groups": { # Expansion of groups.
  "a_key": { # List of calendars that are members of this group.
    "errors": [ # Optional error(s) (if computation for the group failed).
      {
        "domain": "A String", # Domain, or broad category, of the error.
        "reason": "A String", # Specific reason for the error. Some of the possible values are:
            # - "groupTooBig" - The group of users requested is too large for a single query.
            # - "tooManyCalendarsRequested" - The number of calendars requested is too large for a single query.
            # - "notFound" - The requested resource was not found.
            # - "internalError" - The API service has encountered an internal error.  Additional error types may be added in the future, so clients should gracefully handle additional error statuses not included in this list.
      },
    ],
    "calendars": [ # List of calendars' identifiers within a group.
      "A String",
    ],
  },
},
"timeMin": "A String", # The start of the interval.
```

}

This should be simple to use to generate what you need.

You can have a play in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.freebusy.query) just remember to turn on the OAuth switch.

Note that minimum parameters are:

{
"timeMin":"2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"timeMax":"2015-02-01T00:00:00Z"
}